# Why superposition of energy states is allowed before measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons, superposition

I read that the electron can be in superposition between the ground state and the next higher energy state until we measures it, how is it possible because electron should be at the lowest energy state right?

Comment: Be careful with words like "wants" in this context. Electrons aren't people.

Comment: “Should” doesn’t imply “is”. You can excite an electron into a state of higher energy, or superpositions of various energy states. Eventually it will return to the ground state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only it can be in a superposition of energy eigenstates before the measurement, it can remain in sich a superposition after a measurement of any observable other than the energy. In fact if you e.g. try to determine whether the electron is located in some region of space the result will necessarily be a superposition of energy eigenstates.

But let's talk more about your statement that the electron "wants" to be in the ground state. If there was just one atom without any emission and absorption processes any energy eigenstate would be a stationary state and live forever. However because the atom is coupled to the electromagnetic field it can emit a photon. If all these emitted photons fly away to infinity unobstructed then indeed the quantum state of the atom itself will *asymptotically* tend to just the ground state. However even in such situation of one hydrogen atom in the empty space this process will take time and if you prepare an atom in a superposition of the energy eigenstate it will not immediately drop into a ground state.

Of course the atom not only can emit a photon. It can also absorb a photon. It also can participate in all kinds of interactions with other stuff in the universe. The generic result will be that the atom will not "want" to be in the ground state

Comment: Hi I read that superposition is having every possible states at the same time but your answer is suggesting not knowing the states beforehand correct? This two statements are not the same thing right?